# Installation of Cordova on fresh install of latest Ubuntu LTS for Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, cordova, gradle

I expect running `cordova run android` in the path of an existing project (which has been shown to work on other systems) to work on my system. I initially tried the recommended installation instructions on Cordova's website, including the platform-specific instructions, but they didn't work. I've tried following posts on StackOverflow that addressed the pieces of the problem one at a time, but after seeing a great diversity of error messages and following different approaches, I need to go back to a simpler approach and perspective.

Starting from [a fresh install of the latest LTS version of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), 18.04.4, how do I install Cordova and its dependencies in order to work on the existing project?

Here are some additional considerations.

- I'm looking for step-by-step instructions, not an 'approach'.
- I have not found a 'duplicate' of this question that actually worked.
- I've tried too many combinations of advice to have a reasonable description of "what I've tried"
- My question is [on topic according to the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as I am asking about software tools that are commonly used by programmers and my problem is practical and answerable.
- You will not need additional details on my system as the fresh install of the specific version mentioned above will be my system. You should be able to reproduce this process on any such system.
- I cannot share the project itself as it is proprietary, which is a common situation for software developers.
- The focus of this post is narrow. I want `cordova run android` to have the specified behaviour of its documentation.
- This question does not require opinions in its answer. It will be a repeatable and independently verifiable observation whether the answer works, and therefore an objective fact.

---

UPDATE 1

The following is some configuration information of the system where `cordova run android` on the existing project worked.

- Win10 Home, Version 1909, Build 18363.720
- Node v6.2.2
- java version 1.8.0_171
- javac 1.8.0_112
- Gradle 4.7
- JDK for original Java from Oracle, not Oracle's Open JDK
- Cordova 8.0.0
- Android studio 3.1.3
- Git 2.19.1.windows.1

---

Comment: Someone voted to close this post as off topic, but as I stated, "My question is on topic according to the help center as I am asking about software tools that are commonly used by programmers and my problem is practical and answerable."

Comment: The same person who voted to close specified that "It's seeking debugging help but needs more information.", but did not comment on what information is missing. I have stated desired behaviour, and explained why a 'specific error' and 'shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem' can be reasonably waived.

Comment: To clarify, this is a clear question that should have a well-defined answer, and therefore 'additional information' on a specific error is not required.